# Reading multiple lines from server

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, stringbuilder, printwriter

I'm open for other ways to do this, but this is my code:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        try(Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 7789)) {
            BufferedReader incoming = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter outgoing = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String send = "";
            String response = "";

            while (!send.equals("logout")){
                System.out.println("Enter Command: ");
                send = scanner.nextLine();
                outgoing.println(send);
                while ((response = incoming.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(response);
                    sb.append(response);
                    sb.append('\n');

                    }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Client Error: "+ e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I do get response from the server, but the program is getting stuck in the inner while loop `while ((response = incoming.readLine()) != null)`, so i can't enter a second command. how do i break the loop if the incoming response is done ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using a `while` loop for checking `send` to not equal "logout"?

Comment: yes, logout is the command for breaking the connection. after that the server just kickes the client without any extra info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `incoming.readLine()` will only return `null` if the socket is closed, otherwise it will block and wait for more input from the server.

If you can change the server, you could add some marking that the request was fully processed and then check it like this `while ((response = incoming.readLine()) != "--finished--")`.

If you cannot, try this:

```
while(response.isEmpty()){
    if(incoming.ready()){ //check if there is stuff to read
        while ((response = incoming.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(response);
            sb.append(response);
            sb.append('\n');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the server, it isn't open source or mine. Is there another way to get all data just from the client side?

Comment: Thank you very much. incoming.ready was the missing part that i needed.